# What do the stars mean on the Bell Labs Pins (company culture)?

Tags: history

I frequently see these kinds of pins go for sale,

[image: Bell Labs Star Pins]

Both of the two pins in the picture read "Bell Telephone Laboratories 1875". One of the pins has two stars, the other three.

What did it mean to have two-stars, three-stars, or four-stars on your lapel pin? Were these given to engineers, or sales people?

Comment: One star per 5 years of service inside the company. The year 1875 commemorates Bell's successful phone experiments, it's part of the motif.

Comment: @Janka that's exactly what I'm looking for, if you want to make it an answer (and especially if you have a citation or have a source).

Comment: Nothing but hearsay.

Comment: Why do you reckon this is off-topic? We've had [another badge identification question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1261/278) that went down quite well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to the lead by "Janka" in the comments, these are merely five year service pins,

[image]

From [Bell Laboratories "Record" (their magazine) 1944 August](https://www.americanradiohistory.com/Archive-Bell-Laboratories-Record/40s/Bell-Laboratories-Record-1944-Aug.pdf),

> Charles G. Spencer of the Switching Development Department, with the longest service record of any present member of the Laboratories, receives his 45 year pin from Dr. Buckley.

[Dr. Oliver E. Buckley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oliver_Ellsworth_Buckley) was the chairman of the board of the Bell Telephone Laboratories. This seems to be part of a long standing tradition at Bell Labs to commemorate employment anniversaries in lustrums.

[image: listing of employment anniversaries from "Record"]